# Show $f$ is bijective

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

> Let $ U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ open and $ f\in \mathcal{C}^1(U) $ with $ c>0 $ such that for all $ x,y\in U $ it applies $ \|f(x)-f(y)\|\geq c \cdot \|x-y\| $. Now let $ Df(x)\in \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R}) $ for all $ x\in U $.
>
> If $ U=\mathbb{R}^n $ then $ f $ is bijective.

*My idea(s):*

1.) To show $ f $ is injective I use: For all $ x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n $ with $ x\neq y $ it applies $ 0<c\cdot \|x-y\|\leq \|f(x)-f(y)\| $  such that $ f(x)\neq f(y) $ and I'm done. But I don't any idea how to show $ f $ surjective.

2.) I try to use the **Inverse function theorem**. But I have the following problem with that wich I cannot solve. This theorem inculdes that for a point $ x_0\in U $ there exists an open set $ \tilde{U}\subseteq U $ such that $ f_{|\tilde{U}} \tilde{U}\to f(\tilde{U}) $ is bijective and the local inverse of f called $ g:f(\tilde{U})\to \tilde{U} $ is continuously differentiable. But I don't see why it would apply that $ f(\mathbb{R}^n)=\mathbb{R}^n $. Here I just have the input value $ x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n $ which doesn't help me especially to show f is surjective.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3614888/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1111299/42969

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3614888/forall-x-y-in-mathbbrn-x-y-in-u-left-lvert-fx-fy-right-rvert) answer your question?

Comment: Not really. I also know that $ f(\mathbb{R}^n)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n  $ is open.

Comment: How can I show that $ f(\mathbb{R}^n) $ is also closed without using the boundary of $ f(\mathbb{R}^n) $?

Answer (score 0):

Big Hint :

A $C^1$ map $f:\Bbb{R^n}\to \Bbb{R^n}$  is globally invertible ( more specifically a $C^1$-diffeomorphism) iff  determinant of the Jacobian matrix never vanishes and $\|f(y) \|\to \infty$ as $\|y\|\to \infty$

See [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.5930)